# gitignore all files in folders but keep folder structure

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following folder structure:

```
/foo/
/foo/test.txt
/foo/.gitkeep
/foo/bar/test.txt
/foo/bar/.gitkeep
/foo/bar/baz/test.txt
/foo/bar/baz/.gitkeep
```

Now I want to exclude all files in the folder "foo" and all files in its subfolders (and subsubfolders), except all the .gitkeeps (so that the folder structure is kept). This should also work for more than 3 levels of subfolders.

The following gitignore-rules work:

```
/foo/**
!/foo/**/
!/foo/**/.gitkeep
```

Can somebody explain, why this works? Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: I think this should be cleaner: /foo/**/*    !/foo/**/.gitkeep

Comment: Nope, not working. /foo/test.txt is not ignored, /foo/bar/.gitkeep is ignored, /foo/bar/baz/.gitkeep is ignored.

Answer (score 49):

The rule is simple:

[**It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)

That is why you need to

- ignore files and folders recursively:

  ```
  /foo/**
  ```

(if you only ignore `/foo/`, that is the folder, then no amount of '`!`' exclusion rule will work, since the `foo/` folder itself is ignored: Git will stop there)

- Then exclude folders from the ignore rules:

  ```
  !/foo/**/
  ```
- *Before* whitelisting files like the `.gitkeep`

  ```
  !/foo/**/.gitkeep
  ```

That works because the `.gitkeep` parent folders are excluded from the ignore rules.

As opposed to Bernardo original proposal ([before his edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46353524/revisions)):

```
/foo/** 
!**/.gitkeep
```

If does not exclude folders from the `/**` ignore rule, so the exclusion rule for *files* is inoperative.

You can check that with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- /path/to/.gitkeep
```

As mentioned in [scm `.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

- using '`*`' is the same as '`**`'
- using `!.gitkeep` (without any / anchor) would exclude that file recursively.

In both cases, '`recursively`' is the key term which explains why exclusion rules can apply: if you ignore a folder (like `.` or `/foo/`), you won't be able to exclude anything inside that folder.
But if you ignore elements (files and folder) *recursively* (`*` or `**`), *and* exclude folders from gitignore rules (again through recursive rule `!*`), *then* you can exclude (white-list) files.

Comment: thank you for this! I've looked high and low, but all the .gitkeep solutions fail to mention the logic behind recursive ignoring and exceptions.

Answer (score 6):

I've done it. It seems that what is needed is a `.gitignore` file inside the desired folder.

Look at [this repository](https://github.com/bernardoduarte/allow-only-gitkeep), which does exactly what you want.

I've tried to add any filename inside `foo/`, `foo/bar/` and `foo/bar/baz/` but it only accepts .gitkeep.

The trick is to create a .gitignore with this content, *inside the folder*:

```
*
!*/
!.gitignore
!.gitkeep
```

---

**[Edit: Added based on comments]**

And you should be able to shorten this to:

```
*
!*/
!.git*
```

Though it may be less clear in the future what was intended.

While this solution doesn't shorten the number of lines required from your original `.gitignore`, this does have several other advantages - the main one being that this will be a `.gitignore` file *inside the folder*, which means it can be a clean file that has just these lines, and is specific to just this folder.

That means this `.gitignore` file can be easily moved into any specific folder that requires this filter.  Also, the entire folder can be easily moved around within the repo, or even moved to a different repo, without needing to modify the `.gitignore`.  It is much cleaner and more maintainable, and not buried in the typically large `.gitignore` file in the repo's root folder.

Comment: This does not work. With this rule, only the following file is ignored:
**/foo/.gitkeep**

I want also those files being not ignored:
**/foo/bar/.gitkeep**
**/foo/bar/baz/.gitkeep**

Comment: It seems that one cannot simplify the statement, which now makes sense to me. I wonder why I nowhere found that specific answer.

Comment: @DavidVielhuber I've done it check my edited solution, it includes a example repository to test. Try adding any filename inside those folders and you will see that it doesn't accept any ;D

Comment: Yes, that also works, but has some caveats (4 lines instead of 3 and one general ignore rule).

Comment: The thing is, with this one you put inside the desired folders, without having to put their names inside the ignore, making it agnostic and, therefore, flexible and extensible. All you need with this one is to copy and move it around to use it elsewhere in another folder or even in another project. And for the 4 rows of rules, I think if you put a general !.git* exception it will catch both !.gitignore and !.gitkeep.

Comment: @DavidVielhuber Also, by using the .gitignore inside the folder allows you to change names of the folder without having to change any line of the .gitignore.

Comment: You're right, seems like a personal choice. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but I'd like to raise an important issue with this:

- With mounted data folders, this causes **git** commands such as `git status` to run *very slowly*, because the commands still sweep through all the files (despite not committing them), which will run slowly through a network.
- More unpredictably, this causes **Oh My Zsh** (if installed) to hang the shell for a while after each command, because it silently checks for the git branch (I raised this [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9046)).

One way to work around this is to do the following:

1. Add this to your `.gitignore`:

```
data/**
!data/**/
!data/**/.gitkeep
```

2. `git add data`
3. Remove the second line from your .gitignore:

```
data/**
# !data/**/
!data/**/.gitkeep
```

4. `git add .gitignore`
5. `git commit`

This commits the data directory structure to git, and ensures that any future `git` calls will completely ignore the contents of your data subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

Empty directories cannot be committed to Git. So create a README.md file or any empty file and ignore all other files (using pattern match). This way directory will be committed with placeholder file.

Comment: This is helpful to know. Instead of using `.gitkeep` as the question post was using, I was able to use `.gitignore` in the subdirectory as a file so that the subdirectories are not empty.